# Modyfing an item in a list of a list doesn't update the UI

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I have pretty complicated case where data from API comes in the form of a list which contain lists and these inner lists (there is multiple of them btw) finally contain entries. So what I did is that I have collection view and in that collection view I have another collection view which serves as a template.

So in this inner collection view I have selected item binded to a Entry type property from my viewmodel. I can easily gather the data about the clicked item but trying to modify anything will not update the UI. Which might be because I'm modifying this property in a viewmodel instead of in list where I have it. (I have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented) So I'm looking for solution to solve this.

I will send my view , viewmodel, and my classes for you to see what exactly is going on.

View:

```
               <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding AnimListsList}"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                            SelectionMode="None"
                            x:Name="CollectionView1">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" FontSize="30">
                            </Label>
                            <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding entries}"
                            BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                            ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                            SelectionMode="Single"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding BindingContext.Entry, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"
                            x:Name="CollectionView2">
                                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackLayout>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding media.Title.Romaji}"></Label>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding progress}"></Label>
                                            <Frame BackgroundColor="Green">
                                                <StackLayout>
                                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Yellow" xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                                                           xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding BindingContext.InfoCommand, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"></Frame>
                                                    <Frame BackgroundColor="Red" xct:TouchEffect.NativeAnimation="True"
                                                           xct:TouchEffect.Command="{Binding BindingContext.InfoCommand2, Source={x:Reference Name=AnimeListPagee}}"></Frame>
                                                </StackLayout>
                                            </Frame>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            </CollectionView>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

My property to which I bind to as selected item in my collection view

```
    public ListEntry entry;
    public ListEntry Entry
    {
        get => entry;
        set
        {
            if (value == entry)
                return;

            entry = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

A task that is fired by command binded to one of the frames in my view

```
        async Task Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Entry.media.Title.Romaji} +");
        Entry.progress++;
    }
```

Relevant part of my model:

```
public class Media
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string BannerImage { get; set; }
    public int? AverageScore { get; set; }
    public int Favourites { get; set; }
    public TitleType Title { get; set; }
    public CoverImageType CoverImage { get; set; }
}
  public class MediaListCollection
{
    public ObservableCollection<lists> lists { get; set; }
}

public class lists
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool isCustomList { get; set; }
    public bool isSplitCompletedList { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ListEntry> entries { get; set; }
}

public class ListEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    public int progress;
    public Media media { get; set; }

    public int Progress
    {
        get => progress;
        set
        {
            if (value == progress)
                return;

            progress = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

The ultimate goal is to modify the selected entry's progress property. Trying to do it the easy way
`Entry.progress++` by modifying the property in the viewmodel did not work. I want these two frames in my view to increase and decrease it as I wish. The reason it is not working is probably the one I mentioned so I am looking for solution to find the right item in the list that is in the list, modify progress property and most importantly make the UI update accordingly. It would be so much easier to do it if it was just a one normal list.

I tried implementing INotifyPropertyChanged to the relevant class and property in my model but that's throwing me an exception when querying to API.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'A member with the name 'progress' already exists on 'OtakuApp.Models.ListEntry'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.
```

This is my code for querying and adding

```
                string token = Preferences.Get("token", "default_value");
            var anilistGraphQlHttpClient =
                new GraphQLHttpClient("https://graphql.anilist.co", new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

            anilistGraphQlHttpClient.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

            var requestAnimeList = new GraphQLRequest(
                "query { MediaListCollection(userId: 5154007, type: ANIME) { lists { name isCustomList isSplitCompletedList status entries { media { id episodes title { romaji } } progress status } } } } ");

            var graphQlResponseAnimeList =
                await anilistGraphQlHttpClient.SendQueryAsync<ResponseType>(requestAnimeList);

            foreach (var name in graphQlResponseAnimeList.Data.MediaListCollection.lists)
            {
                AnimListsList.Add(name);
            }
```

Comment: please read [ask] and review the rules about posting code.  The **relevant** portions need to be included IN your post, not in an offsite repo.  None of your models implement INPC so changes to their properties will not update the UI.

Comment: Okay, so I implemented INPC on the one relevant class and property in my models but now  it's just throwing an exception when doing the query to API "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'A member with the name 'progress' already exists on 'OtakuApp.Models.ListEntry'. Use the JsonPropertyAttribute to specify another name.'
"
And I can't progress further. Bear in mind that as I said I have INPC implemented on the property that I bind to as selected item for my collection view. Or is that not relevant at all?

Comment: please see my earlier comment about posting your code.  I can't help you if I can't see what you're doing

Comment: Okey, I've done that. You can now take a look. If you need to see anything more, let me know

Comment: Why is "Progress" capitalized when your other properties are not?  I suspect the json property is lower cased.  Either change that or use the JsonPropertyAttribute as suggested by the error message.

Comment: I did progress property lower cased and the other one like '_Progress' . This seems to be working for me.

Do you might know why I have like 4 items visible only from the first list? I tried doing stuff like VerticalOptions Fill on collection views but still can't see them all. Trying to do HeightRequest = 99999 on the outside collection view and 9999 on the inside seems to expose the items so I know they are 'there'. But this is wrong solution to the problem.

Comment: if you're having a different problem you should post a new question